# No Such Element (Selenium)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, xpath

I have checked far and wide for a fix for this. But to no avail. Nothing seems to work. I am trying to locate a Username and Password box to enter in the information. But it comes up with the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="userName"]"}
```

I have tried to find using **id** but still no luck.
Any ideas?

```
username_box = bot.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="userName"]')
```

This is the inspect element

```
<input class="userNameField" maxlength="255" id="userName" name="userName" type="text">
```

Comment: Did you try explicit wait

Comment: else try if its inside a different frame

Comment: I am using **-i** in the command line, so elements loading are not a problem. I have been on the page for 5 minutes now

Comment: It is interactive, so I entered in the command and am sure that the box is fully loaded. So using a **wait** would not be required.
Unless I am misunderstanding what an explicit wait is

Comment: https://www.freekigames.com/educational-trivia
That is the link to the website. Just click the orange **Login/Sign Up** box. You cannot inspect the box, but you can inspect the word and find the box easily

Comment: Also I cannot switch frames because it gives me the exact same error message

Comment: wait for i frame to apear then switch to frame , then sendkeys to input, then switch back to parent frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bot.driver.switch_to.frame(bot.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="jPopFrame_content"]'))
```

Comment: Hi John, is this what worked for you? If so, it would be good to add a small amount of info about how you arrived at it, just to help future readers who might have a slightly different but not quite different enough to ask a new question kind of issue. Thanks!